# WooCommerce - Paypal Transaction ID

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I am developing a plugin for woocommerce and I would like to get the paypal transaction `id` after the checkout to use the paypal api.

I search the documentation but couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

By looking into the code of the PayPal gateway I found out, that you can access it through `$order->get_transaction_id()` after the payment is completed.

For more questions there is a well defined documentation of their framework. e.g. you can find this function [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html) (inherited from this [class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_get_transaction_id)).

I know this is very later, but I just want to help other people looking for this.

Answer (score -1):

Found an answer myself

```
get_post_meta($order->id, '_transaction_id')
```